# I cannot get my quiz code to work

Tags: php

I am learning to program, so a beginner.
Below I tried to create a simple quiz with php and html.  Each question need to be refreshed (1 question per page).  I am trying to record the total score, but as soon as the page is refreshed (new question is loaded), the previous score disappears.

Could you kindly tell me what I am doing wrong and what I should do to make it work?

Thank you.

```
<?php

// get $pos from address bar
    $pos = $_GET['position'];
    if (!$pos) $pos = 0;

// showing the position (just to see to test.)
echo "position is $pos <br>";



    $questions = array (

    //Array for questions which include qID, calcType, qLayout, numbers (num1, num2,etc.), correctAns.
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(1, 2, 3), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3")),
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(4, 5, 6), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3")),
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(7, 8, 9), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3"))

    );

    $numOfQs= (sizeof($questions));


?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maths Quiz</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<style>

        .questionForm {
            border:1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        form {
            padding-bottom: 20px;

        }

        p {
            font-size:20px;
        }

</style>    


</head>

<body>





        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 questionForm">



                    <form method="POST">


                        <div class="form-group">


                            <p>
                                <?php


                                    // Generate question here.
                                    echo "Question ".($pos+1)." of ".$numOfQs;

                                    $question = $questions[$pos][1];
                                    $calcType = $questions[$pos][2];
                                    $qLayout = $questions[$pos][3];
                                    $num1 = $questions[$pos][4][0];
                                    $num2 = $questions[$pos][4][1];
                                    $correctAns = $num1 + $num2;

            echo "<h3>$question<br>".$num1." + ".$num2." = ? </h3>";


                                ?>
                            </p>


                            <label for="yourAns">Your answer:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="yourAns" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer here." />

                        </div>



                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />




                    </form>
                                <div>
                    <p><?php

            if ($_POST["submit"])  {


                if($_POST["yourAns"]) {

                    $yourAns=$_POST["yourAns"];

                    if ($yourAns == $correctAns) {

                        echo "Your answer is correct!";

                        $correct[$pos] = 1;


                    } else {

                        echo "Your answer is wrong!</br> Correct answer is ".$correctAns.".";
                        $correct[$pos] = 0;
                    }





                } else {

                    echo "Please enter your answer.";

                }

                // link to $pos + 1
                echo '<br><a href="index.php?position='. ($pos+1) .'">Next page</a><br>';




                $totalCorrect=$correct[0]+$correct[1]+$correct[2];              


            }


            echo "Total correct is $totalCorrect <br>";



        ?>  </p>    


        </div>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

<?php 
echo "Total correct is $totalCorrect <br>";
            print_r($correct);

?>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store the total correct in session so that it persists between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $_SESSION to send the total to another question page (without lose the value with the "refresh").

```
<?php

$totalCorrect = 0;
session_start();
// get $pos from address bar
    $pos = $_GET['position'];
    if (!$pos) $pos = 0;


echo "position is $pos <br>";// showing the position (just to see to test.)



    $questions = array (

    //Array for questions which include qID, calcType, qLayout, numbers (num1, num2,etc.), correctAns.
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(1, 2, 3), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3")),
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(4, 5, 6), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3")),
    array (1, "Addition question", "add", "horizontal", array(7, 8, 9), array(1, "altAns"), array("hint1","hint2","hint3"))

    );

    $numOfQs= (sizeof($questions));


?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maths Quiz</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<style>

        .questionForm {
            border:1px solid grey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        form {
            padding-bottom: 20px;

        }

        p {
            font-size:20px;
        }

</style>    


</head>

<body>





        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 questionForm">



                    <form method="POST">


                        <div class="form-group">


                            <p>
                                <?php


                                    // Generate question here.
                                    echo "Question ".($pos+1)." of ".$numOfQs;

                                    $question = $questions[$pos][1];
                                    $calcType = $questions[$pos][2];
                                    $qLayout = $questions[$pos][3];
                                    $num1 = $questions[$pos][4][0];
                                    $num2 = $questions[$pos][4][1];
                                    $correctAns = $num1 + $num2;

            echo "<h3>$question<br>".$num1." + ".$num2." = ? </h3>";


                                ?>
                            </p>


                            <label for="yourAns">Your answer:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="yourAns" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer here." />

                        </div>



                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />




                    </form>
                                <div>
                    <p><?php

            if ($_POST["submit"])  {


                if($_POST["yourAns"]) {

                    $yourAns=$_POST["yourAns"];

                    if ($yourAns == $correctAns) {

                        echo "Your answer is correct!";

                        $_SESSION['correct'][$pos] = 1;


                    } else {

                        echo "Your answer is wrong!</br> Correct answer is ".$correctAns.".";
                        $_SESSION['correct'][$pos] = 0;
                    }





                } else {

                    echo "Please enter your answer.";

                }

                // link to $pos + 1
                echo '<br><a href="?position='. ($pos+1) .'">Next page</a><br>';




                //$totalCorrect=$correct[0]+$correct[1]+$correct[2];              

                $totalCorrect = $_SESSION['correct'][0] + $_SESSION['correct'][1] + $_SESSION['correct'][2];
            }


            echo "Total correct is $totalCorrect<br>";



        ?>  </p>    


        </div>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

<?php 
//echo "Total correct is {$_SESSION['totalCorrect']} <br>";
//            print_r($_SESSION['totalCorrect']);

?>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   



</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: did you even run this? as far as i can see you didn't solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `php session` http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

It will handle values across php pages and it will not reset even you refresh the page unless you set it to reset values.

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting the position parameter in the form.

You've got a link with the get parameter `<a href="....?position=..">`

But when you click the link, that does not submit the form, and the user's answer does not get submitted.

You can fix it by changing the `$_GET[..]` to `$_POST[..]`, removing the link and using a hidden input to pass the position parameter so it's posted instead of getted (gotten?).